# line numbers (lineno) with non-standard paragraphs

Tags: line-numbering, fbox, lineno, linenumber

I am using the article class with the `lineno` package, to provide line numbers, and would like to highlight certain paragraphs with a vertical bar, as in the example below. How can I keep the line numbers for such paragraphs?

All the packages I have tried (`fbox` in this example, but any method would be fine) do not play nice with `lineno`.

**Edit:** The solution suggested by Simon failed to work for me. After some experimentation, the culprit turned out to be the `pagewise` option for the `lineno` package:

**Edit2:** See my answer below, it just needed `\realpagewiselinenumbers`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[pagewise]{lineno}
\usepackage{fbox}

\begin{document}
    \linenumbers
    
    \noindent How can I combine these two paragraphs to have linenumbers \emph{and} the red bar?
    
    \nolinenumbers % do not number the box
    \begin{quote}
        \fparbox[L,boxrule=2pt,lcolor=red,boxsep=.5em]{\internallinenumbers\lipsum[4]}
    \end{quote} 
    \linenumbers % restart numbering
    
    \begin{quote}
        \lipsum[4]
    \end{quote}
\end{document}
```

I will post a full working (in a way) approach in a separate answer.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package `lineno` allows to add  numbers inside boxes with `\internallinenumbers`

[image: a]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{fbox}   

\begin{document}
    \linenumbers
    
    \noindent How can I combine these two paragraphs to have linenumbers \emph{and} the red bar?
    
    \nolinenumbers % do not number the box
    \begin{quote}
        \fparbox[L,boxrule=2pt,lcolor=red,boxsep=.5em]{\internallinenumbers\lipsum[4]}
    \end{quote} 
    \linenumbers % restart numbering
    
    \begin{quote}
        \lipsum[4]
    \end{quote}
\end{document}
```

Or define a new environment

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{fbox}

%**************************************** added <<<<<<<<<<<
\usepackage{environ}
\NewEnviron{RedQuote}[1]{%  new enviroment quote + red rule + line numbers <<<<<<
\nolinenumbers
\begin{quote}
    \fparbox[L,boxrule=2pt,lcolor=red,boxsep=.5em]{%
    \internallinenumbers%
    \BODY}
\end{quote}
\linenumbers
}
    

\begin{document}
\linenumbers

\noindent How can I combine these two paragraphs to have linenumbers \emph{and} the red bar?


\begin{RedQuote}
        
    \lipsum[4]
\end{RedQuote}  

\begin{quote}
    \lipsum[4]
\end{quote}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Unfortunately `\internallinenumbers`, at least in my real-world document, does exactly what it claims to, i.e. running a separate, “internal” counter. I have managed to synchronize this using some additional “counter arithmetics“, but it's far from ideal.

Comment: @Ingmar Thank you for your comments!. To help other readers with a similar problem, it would be nice if you update the MWE using something similar to your actual document or accept the answer as it meets the conditions of the question and post a new question.

Comment: The culprit turned out to be the `pagewise` option, which was admittedly missing from my MWE. I have found a working solution for me now, thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: It just needed `\realpagewiselinenumbers`, go figure … Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** After going through the code, I stumbled across another command that does exactly what I need, `\realpagewiselinenumbers`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{fbox}


\begin{document}
    \realpagewiselinenumbers
    \linenumbers
    
    \noindent How can I combine these two paragraphs to have linenumbers \emph{and} the red bar?
    
    \nolinenumbers % do not number the box
    \begin{quote}
        \fparbox[L,boxrule=2pt,lcolor=red,boxsep=.5em]{\internallinenumbers\lipsum[4]}
    \end{quote} 
    \linenumbers % restart numbering
    
    \begin{quote}
        \lipsum[4]
    \end{quote}
\end{document}
```

[image]